# Scrolling the div content through JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know we can use JavaScript function `scrollTo` and `scrollBy` to scroll the browser scrollbar, but I dont want to scroll the browser scroll bar. I want to scroll the content of the DIV with `overflow: scroll` (Means the scrollbar which HTML provide to a div when we set its CSS property `overflow` to scroll).

Comment: Hellooooo out there , why you are downvoting my question ? `Reason Please ?`

Comment: I don't know why they are downvoting your question, but the backtick is for inline code, don't use it inappropriately.

Comment: I would guess your "question" is getting downvoted because there is no actual question. If you post a specific question, the code for what you are attempting, along with text highlighting a specific point where it's is failing, you are much more likely to get upvotes (and help).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` property to scroll your DIV element, it work on BODY element too.

[Live jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tTW8m/1/)